# Assembler. Call

Tags: ассемблер, машинный-код

Я вроде читал много по Assembler'у, но так и недопонял, как именно работает call и callf. У меня появилось два вопроса: 
1) Call - **"близкий"** переход. Что значит **"близкий"**? Чем он отличается от **"дальнего"**? 
2) В какой участок памяти нужно класть код, чтобы получить к нему доступ через call и callf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Близкий переход происходит в пределах сегмента, меняется только IP, а CS остается неизменным. При этом в стек помещается только текущий IP для такого же короткого возврата.

Дальний переход может осуществляться между сегментами, т.е. при нем меняется и IP и CS. В стек при этом помещается так же, "дальний" адрес, т.е. текущий CS:IP.

Код может быть в любом участке памяти, доступном данному виду call. Для близкого вызова код должен быть в пределах того же сегмента.

Обратите внимание, ближние call бывают 2х видов, относительные (код операции E8) и абсолютные (опкод FF). В коде операции относительного вызова находится смещение точки куда происходит переход относительно адреса текущей инструкции. В операции абсолютного вызова находится смещение точки перехода относительно начала текущего сегмента кода.

Comment: Вы очень понятно объяснили, но у меня остался один вопрос: при ближнем переходе нужно указывать адрес относительно текущего сегмента?

Comment: @user263096 Либо начала текущего сегмента, либо относительно адреса текущей команды. Дописал в ответе.